# SQL take only the date xx/xx/xxxx from a variable with time

Tags: sql

i would like to insert into sql a condition to take from a variable of this type: Friday, October 01, 2021 12:00 AM only the date, so as result DD/MM/YYYY.

The variable name is travelperiod and is a data type.

Here the image of the code: [SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqDmV.png)

Thanks

Lorenzo

Comment: "is data type" ? Did you mean its data type is date? If so then you would simply insert. Maybe you should share more details like your backend, language, what you are really trying to do (ie: where does that variable come from? Is it string or you are just sharing a string display of underlying Date\DateTime data type? Do you want to convert to a string as 'dd/MM/yyyy'?).

Comment: Additional detailes: the variable type is "date", i would like to convert this "Friday, October 01, 2021 12:00 AM" into this "01/09/2021"

Comment: What DBMS are you using? "Friday, October 01, 2021 12:00 AM" clearly isn't a date, but a datetime; a certain date at midnight. The only exception I know of is Oracle. They call their datetime data type `DATE` inappropriately. In this DBMS there is hence no difference between a date and a datetime (a date is considered the same as a datetime at midnight), so a tool may not know whether to display the time or not. If this is Oracle and this is a `DATE` then the tool may show you midnight. But you can use this variable as a date, e.g. `select * from mytable where mydate = :travelperiod;`.

Comment: `travelperiod` is a strange name for a date by the way. You could argue that a date has 24 hours so the period is this time range of 24 hours, but for a period I'd rather expect separate `travel_period_start` and either `travel_period_end` or `travel_period_duration`.

Comment: We have salesforce and the type reported is date but its a DateTime as you said. yes the real variable name should be travel period end

Comment: And your DBMS is ____?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add in tag your database, also prefer copy/paste your code instead of showing a screen :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving details :( I will assume "my sql" means MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Not sure if you meant this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('Friday, October 01, 2021 12:00 AM','%W, %M %d, %Y %I:%i %p'), '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: so looking in the image i upload on the question, i how it will be? and is not my SQL sorry. It's sql

Comment: @Lorenzo, what do you mean "it is sql"? SQL Server? Your image doesn't tell anything. It is plain sql that might work against any SQL backend. I didn't see something specific there giving clue about the backend database you are using. And still it is not clear what you are trying to do. Also, next time, instead of picture give code itself. Pictures are not so helpful when the code itself is text.

Comment: @Lorenzo, and also, you were saying "insert" but the SQL in picture is doing a "select". Please explain what you are trying to do.